# How can I run uglify then strip-debug in one task using gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

What I want is to minify all my js in my index.html then remove all **console.logs**

I tried two options:

I TRIED MERGE but only the uglify is executed

```
// Command: gulp useref
gulp.task('useref', function(){
    var _uglify = gulp.src('app/index.html') // .src is the function that is very similar to locating or searching on that file or folder
    .pipe(useref())
    // Minifies only if it's a Javascript file
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
    // Minifies only if it's a CSS file
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/')) // .dest is the location where it will produce the output
    // set to app/, so it will automatically change the index and there's no need to move files 

    var _strip_debug = gulp.src('app/assets/js/scripts.js')
    .pipe(stripDebug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/js'));

    return merge(_uglify, _strip_debug);
});
```

I tried returning two but only the uglify is executed:

```
    gulp.task('useref', function(){
        return gulp.src('app/index.html') // .src is the function that is very similar to locating or searching on that file or folder
        .pipe(useref())
        // Minifies only if it's a Javascript file
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
        // Minifies only if it's a CSS file
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/')) // .dest is the location where it will produce the output
        // set to app/, so it will automatically change the index and there's no need to move files 

        return gulp.src('app/assets/js/scripts.js')
        .pipe(stripDebug())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/js'));
    });
```

Comment: Your variable's name is `_uglify` but you passed `uglify` into `merge()`? Does changing that fix anything?

Comment: I changed it, the error was gone. However, the console logs are not removed

Answer (score 1):

I assume the `app/assets/js/scripts.js` is the concatenated JavaScript file that is generated by `gulp-useref`.

In that case using `merge-stream` will not work, because the `app/assets/js/scripts.js` file might not yet exist when you try to `gulp.src()` it. Instead just add another `gulpIf` stage to your first stream:

```
gulp.task('useref', function(){
   return gulp.src('app/index.html')
     .pipe(useref())
     .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', stripDebug()))
     .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
     .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('app/'))
});
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the write answer to the question.